Question MariaDB time zone and Application time zone
I would like to ask you about the MariaDB time zone.

Application: Asia/Seoul, adding ?serverTimezone= UTC to jdbcurl.
MariaDB(docker): @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone,@@system_time_zone set UTC/ docker set UTC


What I expected is that if you put it as KST time in the application, it will be saved as UTC time in the DB, but it will be saved as KST time. Is this a normal flow?
(ex. KST 2024-11-18 14:00:00 insert, i expected UTC 2024-11-18 05:00:00, but db insert 2024-11-18 14:00:00)
I would like to configure the DB as UTC time and the application as Asia/Seoul that I set up, is there a way?

@PostConstruct
void started() {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Seoul"));
}

@PostMapping
public void insertTime() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    log.info(now.toString());

    TImeTest timeTest = TImeTest.builder()
            .createdAt(now)
            .modifiedAt(now)
            .build();

    timeTestRepository.save(timeTest);
}

url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/test?serverTimezone=UTC

DB
[

  {
    "@@global.time_zone": "UTC",
    "@@session.time_zone": "UTC",
    "@@system_time_zone": "UTC"
  }
]


Please show the code that you are using to insert the row.

I have attached the code.

I think you should change serverTimeZone to Asia/Seoul.
Because LocalDateTime doesn't include zone information, it will be just translated into unzoned Datetime string when passed into MySQL query.
MySQL will use the difference between serverTimeZone and db time zone as delta value for incoming Datetime.
So if you set serverTimeZone to Asis/Seoul will result your times saved -9 hours.
Or just using ZonedDateTime is an another option.
